# open listing pages in new tab if we use "Ctrl + Mouse click"

Tags: product-list

please visit this : [Link](http://videomergerapp.com/toys.html)  in

,scroll down to the end of the page.  you can see

[image]

Press "Ctrl" button in keyboard and click on "Mouse" .

The pages are opening in same tab. but i want to open the pages in new tab.

but for "Menu" on top , its working. its opening menu in new tab.

but for pages , its not working.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml

<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
    <div class="pager">
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>
    <p class="amount">
        <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getShowPerPage()): ?>
    <div class="limiter">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $_limit ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
    <div class="pages">
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Page:') ?></strong>
        <ol>
        <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
            <li>
                <a class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
                    <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>
            <li><a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">1</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
            <li><a class="previous_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
            <?php if ($this->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                <li class="current"><?php echo $_page ?></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?>


        <?php if ($this->canShowNextJump()): ?>
            <li><a class="next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if ($this->canShowLast()): ?>
          <li><a class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>
            <li>
                <a class="next<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?> i-next<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">
                    <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForNext() ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif;?>
        </ol>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: working fine in mozilla

Comment: sorry i posted a another link

Comment: i updated the question....

Comment: Javascript must be intercepting the click event. Also you have 2 or 3 version of jQuery running. You're going to have to figure out which of those scripts is controlling the pagination. You can start by trying to remove any scripts that you may not need on category pages.

Comment: @andyjv we will try that....